python3 - download url with javascript enabled webpage
I would like to download a url with python but it response with text:
We're sorry but jfrog webapp doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue

How can I enable javascript support?
import requests 

def download(url,username,apikey):
    filename = "dump.txt"
    s = requests.session() 
    resp = s.get(url,auth=(username, apikey)) 
    file_size = int(resp.headers.get('content-length', 0))
    length = 1024*1024*5
    total = 0
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        with open(filename, 'wb') as out:
            for chunk in resp.iter_content(length):
                total += length
                if file_size > 0:
                    print("[%.2f]\r"%(total/file_size),end="",flush=True)
                out.write(chunk)
    else:
        print(url)
        print("[*] download error:" + str(r.status_code))
        exit(0)
    print("save file to:",filename)
    return
      
def main():
    url = "https://artifactory.sample.com/sample"
    username="xxxx"
    apikey="yyyy"
    download(url,username,apikey)    
    return

main()



Think about what the jfrog webapp will do to download.

request to server with username and apikey, save the reponse session/cookie, etc.
request to server with session/cookie, etc by JavaScript, update the reponse session/cookie, etc.
request to download from server.

Then track the request/response above, and implement them with Python.
I don’t know if I understand it correctly or not.
Hope it helps you.
